# Lightning Component Demo Page

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Does anyone know if there is a page that demonstrates all of the available supported lightning/aura/whatever widgets?  Here is an example of one for the Lightning Dart implementation:

https://lightningdart.com/demo.html

Ideally, each sample would have a source code panel where a developer could copy and paste the code for the desired component.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no official source that demonstrates all of the Lightning Components. If you want to help contribute to a project, I would not be adverse to writing a public source code demo on GitHub that could be installed/etc.

Comment: sfdcfox, I would *love* to do that.  I think it's an absolute requirement for any modern framework.  I've got the same user id on github (mmoo9154).  Let me know how I can help.

Comment: I'll create a repo for this, give me a day to get a basic design up, and we'll go from there; you can submit issues, pull requests, any way you think you can contribute. If you have a design in mind, I'd love to see some examples, maybe from somewhere on the interwebs. My github is brianmfear. Looking forward to it.

Comment: sfdcfox, the Google Material UI has a comprehensive spec with examples *and* source.  Checkout http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/avatar for instance.

Comment: Now that you've added some more comments, I'm not entirely sure what the ask is. Can you email me and we'll take this offline?

Comment: sfdcfox, I'm unclear where to email you. Forgive me if I'm missing something obvious. The ask is for a webpage of samples with source code for all of the SLDS elementos implemented in Lightning.

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense now. My email's on my profile.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the new Lightning Component library at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library. It's a remarkable improvement over the [classic doc site](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref.htm).

Expect more improvements in the new library with every release.

Comment: Kevin, thanks for the response! I do like the Lightning Component Library page.  Unfortunately, it's kind of bottoms up and incomplete.  It's also focused on the Lightning Components, not on the Salesforce Lightning Design System.   SLDS is a complete spec of UI components, their appearance and their behaviour.  What's missing is a comprehensive library of sample SLDS implementations in Apex/XML/JS for use in Lightning Apps and Components.  That's what I hope sfdcfox and I will be doing.  :-)

Comment: I don’t follow your comment about bottoms up. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: The lightning namespace components are an implementation (in Lightning) of many of the SLDS patterns. There are gaps and we’re working to fill them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a misunderstanding what lightning and SLDS are...

The gaps mentioned in the other comments are here. They are closing with every release: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_components_roadmap.htm.

You have two choices right now are to implement SLDS in your own JS/HTML (what you're attempting to do) and wrap them in a re-useable component. There are others who have done this: http://www.lightningstrike.io/

OR

You can wait for the base components, implemented by Salesforce to be released.

Copy-pasting the code for your own implementation grossly misunderstands what the point of lightning component re-usability are all about. Right now, if you wanted to implement a lightning component (or visualforce with a bunch of javascript) your're to copy-paste the HTML in SLDS and then wire up your own javascript interactions.

I hope that makes sense, but the source you're talking about is exactly this:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library

Comment: tsalb, thanks for the comment, and thanks so much for always being up on freenode.com on the #salesforce channel.    It is awesome, but it's not quite what I'm wishing existed (and must exist somewhere).    For instance, someone somewhere at Salesforce has created an interface inventory like [this](https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/9f3517cd-b5ab-4d59-be34-55fa398b8f31/guide-ui-design-1-interface-inventory.png) BTW, if copy and paste "grossly misunderstands", I think I haven't painted the correct picture with my problem statement.

Comment: Since Lightning Experience (LE) has been implemented with Lightning Components, there should be a complete set of examples for each of the UI features presented in LE. Here's a concrete example of a problem I'm currently wrestling with: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/210581/how-do-i-create-a-page-header-for-a-new-record-page-that-can-pin-like-the-high

Comment: I was able to cobble together an interface inventory from the [salesforce-ux/design-system-ui-kit](https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system-ui-kit) on GitHub. [Here's the PDF](https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system-ui-kit/files/1789212/sketch-ui-kit-winter18-sketch.pdf) Many of the items are included in the link you posted @tsalb. If that were an open source project, we could fill in the gaps. Ideally, a developer could just click on the artifact in the interface inventory and go straight to the entry (with sample code) at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library